# Windows shared folder logs

Tags: windows, network-shares

We have shared folder in one of our servers and any others can copy and delete files from this shared folder. Is there any logs written out by Window who is copying and deleting those files? Say I want to see this log in the past few mins, who deleted some files in one of the sub folder of that shared folder.

Any thoughts? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to enable auditing on the server (or domain) and then enable it on your folder.  There's a good article on [Techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Auditing_Windows_Server_2008_File_and_Folder_Access) for Server 2K8, but I think it's pretty much the same for 2K3